# How to integrate radio modules to Linux networking stack

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, network-interface, uart

I want to know whether it is possible to add a radio link (point-to-point) to the link layer of the networking stack on Linux so that programs can communicate using TCP/IP.

Assuming the only way to talk to these devices is over UART, and the necessary radio pairing has been done, is there a simpler way to do this from user space? This is a high-level diagram of how communication happens without this.

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) protocol was developed to provide a data link layer over a serial connection.

In Linux, the PPP protocol is implemented by the [`ppp`](https://github.com/ppp-project/ppp) package, which is almost certainly available as a package for whatever distribution you're using.

You can use the PPP daemon, `pppd`, to establish TCP/IP link between your two systems over your RF UART.

---

Other alternatives include [SLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol), but I don't think there are supported packages implementing that anymore, and [AX.25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AX.25), which was designed for packet radio use. Many distributions do include ax.25 packages, but I don't have any experience with this so I can't comment on whether or not it would be more or less appropriate than using PPP.

---

**UPDATE**

As @stephenkitt mentions, setting up ax.25 under Linux is relatively easy, but it turns out that you can play around with SLIP with nothing but the standard `util-linux` package. Assuming that your UART on both systems is available at `/dev/ttyS1`, on both devices you can run:

```
ldattach SLIP /dev/ttyS1
```

This will give you an interface `sl0`, which you can then configure just like any other network interface:

```
ip addr add 10.9.8.10/24 dev sl0
ip link set sl0 up
```

Comment: AX.25 would as you say be more appropriate for general packet radio, and is simple to set up — see [this howto](https://www.pakettiradio.net/debian_ax25_mini-howto/) for example. However PPP might be appropriate for the OP’s scenario; it’s not clear what the radio link is supposed to look like.